# After adding a slave to Master - Master configuration, slave syncs from only one master

Tags: mysql, replication

Futher to my previous [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39366/adding-slave-to-existing-master-master-config-in-mysql-throws-foreign-key-constr),

Here is what we have

```
      +<------+
      |       ^
      V       |
S1<---M1      M2
      |       ^
      V       |
      +-------+
```

what happens is Upon making any drop, create, update or insert on M1, the slave S1 Syncs the changes in M1. But when we are trying to do the same in M2, we are not getting any changes synced to the slave S1. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: When you do a change on M2 does M1 get this changes?

Comment: @altmannmarcelo:Yes. It happens

Comment: Then follow what @derek-downey says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure you have [`log_slave_updates`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) enabled on M1, so that any changes that M1 makes via replication from M2 gets written to M1's master log (and thus replicated to S1).

Don't worry, the entries in M1's binary log will not get re-replicated to M2. M2 will ignore any updates which originated from its `server-id`.

Comment: Hey Derek, I miss your quick-and-dirty answers. +1 !!!

Comment: @Derek: Hey Thanks man. We figured out late in the afternoon