# Upgrade mysql from 5.0 to 5.5 in master-master configuration leads to broken replication

Tags: mysql, replication, locking, multi-master

We created two new mysql servers running 5.5.  Our old server were 5.0.

The two servers are set up with master-master replication - this was the case for the two 5.0 servers which had no issues.

We have some long running select queries (40-50 sec), and when they are run replication breaks - we have to skip a couple of records to get replication restarted.  This is consistent and repeatable.  I suspect that some tables are getting updated on each server, but replication is paused trying to update a locked table - and when it is done, each server is trying to send data to the other and replication is broken.

I am seeing a lot of "waiting for table level lock" on select statements when this long query is running.

Is there a setting I've missed to prevent selects from locking tables? Is there some other cause, or any way to fix this?

Comment: Is any or all of your data MyISAM ???

Comment: Yes, it's all MyISAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the data is MyISAM, you should expect table locks rather frequently since INSERT , UPDATE, and DELETE command issues a full table lock.

If you have a lot of tables that use auto increment keys, you should add the following

Server1

```
[mysqld]
auto_increment_increment = 5
auto_increment_offset = 1
```

Server2

```
[mysqld]
auto_increment_increment = 5
auto_increment_offset = 2
```

This will prevent PRIMARY KEY collisions with autoincrement columns

I have other suggestions in my post [I have been tasked with Mysql Master-Master replication?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68366/i-have-been-tasked-with-mysql-master-master-replication/68413#68413)

Comment: That seems to have helped - I wondering why with a 5.0.x system it wasn't need, but we started seeing errors on the 5.5 system?